# Python Future Composition

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

Suppose a library has two functions, the first function takes a url and returns a `Future` of a `Connection`:

```
def create_connection(url)
"""
:return tornado.gen.Future containing connection
"""
```

And a second function which takes a Connection, not a Future of Connection, and returns a Future of a `Channel`:

```
def create_channel(connection):
"""
:return tornado.gen.Future containing channel
"""
```

**How do I bind those two functions together to create a Future of a Channel given a url (without using `await`)?**

Something of the form:

```
url = "doesn't matter"

channel_future = create_connection(url).bind(lambda c: create_channel(c))
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a coroutine (decorated with `gen.coroutine`) and yield the futures returned by `create_connection` and `create_channel`.

```
@gen.coroutine
def bind_things_together():
    connection = yield create_connection(url)
    channel = yield create_channel(connection)

    # do something else ...
```

In the code example above, the `connection` and `channel` variables are not futures, but actual connection and channel objects, because yielding a Future returns it's result.

When you set the result on the connection future, Tornado will call `bind_things_together.next()` to move the coroutine forward. Then in the next line, you pass `connection` to `create_channel`. When you set the result on channel future, Tornado will again call `.next()` to move the coroutine forward. At which point you can do other things.

**EDIT:** On reading your question again, it seems that you want to access the future for channel. In that case, you don't have to yield `create_channel()`:

```
@gen.coroutine
def bind_things...():
    ...
    channel_future = create_channel(connection)
    # if later you want the channel object, just yield channel_future
```

---

**NOTE:** If you call `bind_things_together()` from another function, you will need to decorate that function with `gen.coroutine` as well. Also, any function decorated with `gen.coroutine` will automatically return a Future. So, you have to use `yield` keyword in the caller to get the result of `bind_things_together()`.